# Telnet router commands

Tags: networking, router, telnet

I have an actiontec xdsl router (c1000a) that I am telnetting to but I can't get a list of commands for it. The only one I've found so far is arp. I haven't found a list of common router commands on google either. I want to see what my options are and see if I can save a boot up script.
Edit: the command list:

```
help  
logout  
exit  
quit  
reboot  
adsl  
xdslctl  
xtm  
brctl  
cat  
loglevel  
logdest  
virtualserver  
ddns  
df  
dumpcfg  
dumpmdm  
meminfo  
psp  
kill  
dumpsysinfo  
dnsproxy  
syslog  
echo  
ifconfig  
ping  
ps  
pwd  
sntp  
sysinfo  
tftp  
voice  
dect  
wlctl  
arp  
defaultgateway  
dhcpserver  
dns  
lan  
lanhosts  
passwd  
ppp  
restoredefault  
route  
save  
swversion  
uptime  
cfgupdate  
swupdate  
exitOnIdle  
wan  
gpv
```

Comment: I would try `<tab><tab>` and `?`. Is it possible it's a busybox linux installation? See if `uname -a` runs and returns anything.

Comment: Thank you very much. ? did the trick

Comment: Awesome! Just for future reference, do you mind posting the command list here?

Comment: @Azz Yea. I'll do that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<tab><tab>` or `?` are common ways of getting command lists on routers and Linux platforms.

Also, some routers run some embedded Linux, like BusyBox. `uname -a` will tell you about the kernel version if you're on a Linux box and you aren't in a restricted shell.